# Does the cross object formula trigger flows?

Tags: formula, flow

I have a cross object formula and a flow, which triggers when the custom objects record is being created or updated.

Now let's assume custom_object__c and opportunity object. custom_object__c.custom_field__c is a cross object formula to the checkbox opportunity.custom_field2__c.

Now my question is: When I change the opportunity.custom_field2__c to true, does the flow "on create/edit" trigger? Because I don't know if this actually counts as an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing a field on object 1 which is referenced in a formula on object 2 will **not count as an edit** on object 2.

Comment: Is there a workaround for this? (Without using a trigger, as the trigger displays an error message, due to a bug of the process builder)

Comment: Instead of a formula field, you could use another data type field and have it populated by a process or trigger with your desired value on edit of object 1. In that case, there will be an edit of object 2.

Comment: What do you mean with 'as the trigger displays an error message, due to a bug of the process builder'? What error are you seeing, and when is it popping up?

Comment: Forgot to select it as the right answer, thank you! Nevermind the error, it's a bit too complex for the comment section